# Find the number of factors of [2^(15).3^(10).5^(6)] which are squares , cubes or both.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- I can find that there are **7** squares of **2**, **5** squares of **3** & **3** squares of **5**.(of the given number)
- I can also figure out that there are **5** cubes of **2** , **3** cubes of **3** & **2** cubes of **5**.(of the given number).
  But i cannot find the requried number of **factors**.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Square factors are $4^k9^m25^n, 0\le k \le 7, 0\le m \le 5, 0\le n \le 3$, so we can choose $k,m,n$ independently in $(7+1)(5+1)(3+1)$ ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squares: # of even numbers from $0$ to $15$ $\times$ # of even numbers from $0$ to $10$ $\times$ # of even numbers from $0$ to $6$. This is $8\cdot 6\cdot 4=192$.

Cubes: same as squares, changing "even" by "multiple of three". This makes $6\cdot4\cdot3=72$.

A number is a cube and a square if and only if it is a sixth power. To count them apply the same, changing "even" by "multiple of six". This time it is $3\cdot 2\cdot 2=12$.

Now apply inclusion - exclusion principle.